# Change the color of text from a certain char to the end of a richTextBox Line

Tags: vb.net, winforms

In my Winform a user selects a radio button. Based on that radio button it reads certain lines from a txt file. I then want it to search for an apostrophe, once it finds the apostrophe, I want it to make all the text in the line after the apostrophe - green (the text is real code so it should color the text just like wit would if it were commented in a compiler).

Question: How to determine the length of the text in the line after the apostrophe?

Here is my code so far...

```
    Dim indexx As Integer = 0
    Dim numOfChars As Integer

    While indexx < RichTxtOut.Text.LastIndexOf("'")
        numOfChars = 0

        'This finds the char index of the first instance of what I am looking for. 
        Dim FoundCharIndex As Integer = RichTxtOut.Find("'", indexx, RichTxtOut.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None)
        'this finds the line the found char resides in 
        Dim LineOfFoundChar As Integer = RichTxtOut.GetLineFromCharIndex(FoundCharIndex)

        Dim startCounting As Boolean = False

        'count the number of characters after the apostrophe
        For li As Integer = 0 To RichTxtOut.Lines(LineOfFoundChar).Count - 1
            If RichTxtOut.Lines(LineOfFoundChar).Chars(li) = "'" Then
                startCounting = True
            End If
            If startCounting Then numOfChars += 1

        Next

        RichTxtOut.Select(FoundCharIndex, numOfChars)

        RichTxtOut.SelectionColor = Color.Green
        numOfChars = 0
        indexx = RichTxtOut.Text.IndexOf("'", indexx) + 1

    End While
```

Comment: I figured it out the problem. RichTxtOut.GetLineFromCharIndex() counts a line that has overflowed onto 2 lines as 1 line. Therefore as more lines overflow, the more incorrect it becomes.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out the problem. RichTxtOut.GetLineFromCharIndex() counts a line that has overflowed onto 2 lines as 1 line. Therefore as more lines overflow, the more incorrect it becomes.
This code actually works I needed to change the way it reads the lines into the RichTextBox

```
For li As Integer = Eachline + 1 To lines.Count - 1

    If lines(li) = Nothing Then

    ElseIf lines(li).Chars(0) = "|" Then
        Exit For
    Else
        For lineChar As Integer = 0 To lines(li).Count - 1
            RichTxtOut.Text &= lines(li).Chars(lineChar)

            If lineChar = 90 Then
                RichTxtOut.Text &= vbNewLine & "        →    "
            ElseIf lineChar = 167 Then
                RichTxtOut.Text &= vbNewLine & "        →    "
            End If
        Next
    End If

    RichTxtOut.Text &= vbNewLine

Next
```